# Should I create an index on a column with repetitive values and where in lookup

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes

I have a materialized view (which is very much a [table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html)) where I need to make `where in` kind of queries. 
The column I want to query (say `view_id`) definitely has repetitions (15-20).

The `where in` queries would also be very large i.e - it would contain a lot of `view_id` to query.

Should I go ahead and create an index on this column?
Will it give me some performance improvements?

I have another column which would help help me have a multi column index(unique). Should this be a better option?

Comment: Not an answer, but many duplicate values means lower cardinality and therefore worse index performance, but it doesn't mean don't try an index.  You can always test the performance.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen for that opinion which I very much reciprocate. But I am not in a position to go ahead with a scalability test as of now. The cardinality is bound to grow with data. But yes, no more than the a factor that would be 1/20 - 1/15 of the actual data. Should I try the 2nd option(multi column index) then?

Comment: Of course a composite index should increase the cardinality but that only helps you if you plan on using both the columns.

Comment: Not at all scoping to use the other column in queries. Ok then,  if I get it right, I am left with trying an index on that single column.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With questions such as these on performance, there is no substitute for testing it with your exact case.  There's little harm in trying it out (even on a production system, but utilize a test system if you can!), other than perhaps *slowing* performance until you undo what you did.  Postgres makes this kind of tinkering safe.

@tim-biegeleisen's first comment is spot on: with your setup, your cardinality is reduced, but that doesn't mean it's not a win.

In short, try it and see.  There is no better answer you will get than what your own dataset and access patterns will give you.